# Apache camel with tika using spring dsl

Tags: apache-camel, apache-tika, spring-dsl

I am trying to search for **tika** example with **camel** using [**spring DSL**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference).

I see the tika connector is available but got no example using spring DSL. I looked all the places including https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples link but no luck so far.

Can any body please help me on it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple unit test at the official repo that may be used as example, IMHO:

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-tika/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/tika/TikaDetectTest.java

Take a look at the [others unit tests](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-tika/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/tika) also.

We could transport the route at the aforementioned test to Spring DSL like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camelContext id="tikaCamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="direct:start"/>
            <to uri="tika:detect"/>
            <to uri="mock:result"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Don't forget to add the component to the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-tika</artifactId>
  <version>${camel-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, will take a look.